# High charts click on one data point the other data points should disable

Tags: highcharts, bar-chart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvRTW.png)For Example In high charts take bar chart.In Bar chart if i clicked on one data point the other data points should disable.Please find the image

Comment: Please find the image line: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCFxX.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `Point.select()` function on point from another chart in select event. If you want to get rid of that point, use `Point.remove()` function instead.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Point.select
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Point.remove
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.point.events.select

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/ha7jxztv/

Comment: Thanks for reply! But i need in a chart to fade out other data points when i click on one data point.please find the image how i need  https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCFxX.png

Comment: You can change points opacity on select/unselect events. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/LLr5aqx6/.